# Compute $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac i{\gcd(i,n)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm

Compute $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac i{\gcd(i,n)}$$

The actual problem description is as follows :
$$\sum_{i=1}^{15}\frac i{\gcd(i,{15})}$$

But I'd like a formula which could be used for large $n$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Your sum contains terms like $\frac 22$ but $2$ clearly isn't $\gcd(2,15)$.  What do you mean?

Comment: Ah, i am extremely sorry, i simply meant summation of (i/gcd(i,n)) where 'i' goes from 1 to n (inclusive) .. Can my query be edited without losing the comments? I am new to this.

Comment: I'll edit it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edits.

Comment: I doubt there is a convenient formula for this.  The sequence of values is [A057661](https://oeis.org/A057661) and you can get links off the OEIS site that might help you.   In particular, this is linked to the Farey numbers and computational methods that work there might work here as well.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I am wrong.  The solution linked to by @RobertZ looks very nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{\gcd(n,i)}&=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{\gcd(n,i)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{\gcd(n,n-i)}\right)\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{\gcd(n,i)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-i}{\gcd(n,i)}\right)\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{\gcd(n,i)}
=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{\gcd(n,i)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\left|\{i\in[1,n]: \gcd(i,n)=d\}\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\left|\{k\in[1,n/d]: \gcd(k,n/d)=1\}\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\varphi(n/d)
=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sum_{d|n}d\varphi(d)\right).
\end{align*}$$
Since $n\to\sum_{d| n}d\varphi(d)$
is multiplicative and for any prime $p$,
$$\sum_{d|p^r}d\varphi(d)=1+\sum_{k=1}^r p^k\varphi(p^k)=1+\sum_{k=1}^r (p^{2k}-p^{2k-1})=\frac{p^{2r+1}+1}{p+1},$$
it follows that
$$f(n):=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{\gcd(n,i)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\prod_{j=1}^m\frac{p_j^{2r_j+1}+1}{p_j+1}\right).$$
where $n=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{r_j}$ is the prime factorization of $n$.
For example:
$$\begin{align*}
f(15)&=f(3\cdot 5)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{3^3+1}{3+1}\cdot \frac{5^3+1}{5+1}\right)=74,\\
f(500)&=f(2^2\cdot 5^3)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{2^5+1}{2+1}\cdot \frac{5^7+1}{5+1}\right)=71616.
\end{align*}$$
More details and references  for this sum can be found in OEIS: [A057661](http://oeis.org/A057661)  (see lulu's comment).

Comment: In the given link, There are two lemmas. Can you please explain them in layman terms. I don't have enough reputation to comment on that thread, nor do I have that much mathematical skills to get around it. It would be great if you could explain with an example.

Comment: In a way the main request was to help explain the lemmas, especially the second one. I dont' feel redirecting one question to another should be the desired answer.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini Thanks for your comment. I completely revised my answer giving a final formula which depends on prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: @RobertZ I have been grappling with more [generalised form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4660727/how-to-find-this-lcm-sum-function-textlcmm-n-textlcmm1-n-cdots) of it, no one has taken a look at my question yet. Your answer caught my attention when I realised I don't yet completely understand the special case of it.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't answer my question, how do you prove $d$ as $gcd$ occurs $\varphi(n/d)$ times?

Comment: @sibillalazzerini I added two more lines...

Comment: Thanks. I kind of get it now . for the generalised case so I would have to substract $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}|(gcd(i,n)=d)|$ from $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|(gcd(i,n)=d)|$ . I am not able to express that in closed form like the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|(gcd(i,n)=d)|$ . It would be great if you could take  a look. It should be doable by something like sum of totients or difference of totient. I am considering sum/difference of totients as closed form.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini Finding a closed form for the partial sum $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}|(\gcd(i,n)=d)|$ seems to be hopeless... But I might be wrong ;-)

Comment: So what's the best idea you have than iterating through all $m-1$ $i$'s. For generalised related comments I would appreciate if you comment on that questions thread, it would help me track better in future.